# nltk. Is it possible to count one word in different form as one word(see, saw = see = 2)

Tags: python, nltk

I try to analyze a text and to count amount words in the text. But i need each word in different forms count as one word.
As example:

```
document = "I your hand. I see your hands."
```

see = 2
face = 2
I know how bring the word to dictionary form.

```
document = "I saw your face I see your faces"
sentences = nltk.word_tokenize(document)
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
for key, val in freq.items():
    print(lemmatizer.lemmatize(key.lower(), pos="v"))
```

i got this one
I saw your face I see your faces
i saw
your
face
see
face

It look OK.Except saw
A word can be different part of speech. Like saw is verb past tense and noun, singular.
So I need add part of speech tags.

```
document = "I saw your face I see your faces"
sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(document)
taggeDocument = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(document))
for sent in sentences:
    print(nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sent)))
```

Now I have tagged text. But i don't know how to bring the words to dictionary form.

What I want:
In final I want something like this
('I', 'PRP',2), 
('see', 'VBP',2),
'face', 'NN', 2),
and so on.
Thank in advance.

Comment: What you want is to reduce different grammatical forms of the same verb to a single canonical representation. That is called stemming.  Look up *stemming* in your NLTK documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes I want to tag part of speech, than to reduce each word to canonical form and then to count how many times it found in a text. In fact I want to analyze a text and found words that I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Lemmatization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) to turn words into their dictionary form.

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
document = "I saw your face I see your faces"

##create list of pos
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(document)
tokens_with_pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
print "tokens and their pos tag"
print tokens_with_pos
pos_list = []
for word,pos in tokens_with_pos:
    pos_list.append(pos)

##create list of lemmas
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
lemmas = []
lemma_string = ""
for token in tokens:
    lemma = wnl.lemmatize(token)
    lemmas.append(lemma)
    lemma_string += " "+lemma

##zip list of pos and list of lemmas
lemma_pos = zip(lemmas,pos_list)
##turn list into a set to remove duplicates
lemma_pos_set = set(lemma_pos)

##create freq dist of lemmas
fdist = nltk.FreqDist()
for word in nltk.word_tokenize(lemma_string):
    #word.lower turns the words to lowercase
    fdist[word.lower()] += 1

#create list for lemma pos and frequency
lemma_pos_freq = []

#insert lemma, pos and frequency of lowercase lemma to list
for lemma,pos in lemma_pos_set:
    lemma_pos_freq.append((lemma,pos,fdist[lemma.lower()]))

print "lemmas with pos tags and lemma frequency"
print lemma_pos_freq
```

output:

```
tokens and their pos tag
[('I', 'PRP'), ('saw', 'VBD'), ('your', 'PRP$'), ('face', 'NN'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('see', 'VBP'), ('your', 'PRP$'), ('faces', 'VBZ')]
lemmas with pos tags and lemma frequency
[(u'face', 'VBZ', 2), ('I', 'PRP', 2), ('face', 'NN', 2), ('your', 'PRP$', 2), ('see', 'VBP', 1), ('saw', 'VBD', 1)]
```

There are two entries for "face" in the result. This is because the two occurrences of face are tagged with different part of speech tags.
The word saw is not turned to "see" by lemmatizing. Lemmatization does not work in all cases.

The zip function makes an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. See https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip .

Instead of lemmatization you can also try stemming. See http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html.
Example of stemming:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english", ignore_stopwords=True)
print(stemmer.stem("having")
```

Code is available at https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/https-stackoverflow.com-questions-57004127.

Comment: Thanks friend!
It's really what I'm looking for.